# select column value based on index name in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame named `score_df` having one column named `Score` and there are names of indices as following

```
           Score
year       0.029827
yesterday  0.029827
you        0.089482
zeros      0.029827
zones      0.029827
```

I have another `df` having a column named `df['keywords']` having various keywords. I need to iterate over this column and search in indices of `score_df` and if index matches with keyword I need to append it's `Score` value in a list. I am using following code.

```
for key_w in df['keyword'].to_list():
    result = score_df.loc[key_w, :]
```

But it is giving `KeyError: 'keyword value'`. Can some help me how can I select required value? Thank you

Comment: error is for `print ( df['keyword'])` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with default inner join:

```
print (score_df)
              Score
year       0.029827
yesterday  0.029827
you        0.089482
zeros      0.029827
zones      0.029827

print (df)
     keyword
0      aaaaa
1  yesterday
2        you

print (score_df.merge(df, left_index=True, right_on='keyword'))
      Score    keyword
1  0.029827  yesterday
2  0.089482        you

L = score_df.merge(df, left_index=True, right_on='keyword')['Score'].tolist()
print (L)
[0.029827, 0.089482]
```

Or select index by column `keyword` in [`Index.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html) and [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
L = score_df.loc[score_df.index.isin(df['keyword']), 'Score'].tolist()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method [`filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html#pandas.DataFrame.filter). For example:

df1

```
   col
A    0
B    1
C    2
```

df2

```
  keys
0    A
1    B
2    Z


df1.filter(df2['keys'], axis=0)
```

Output:

```
   col
A    0
B    1
```

To convert it to list use `tolist()`